# Using unix & php get subfolders' names to put into a .csv

Tags: php, unix, csv, sed, cat

I have zip file that I get that, when unzipped, has several subfolders each containing a csv called report.csv:

```
the_folder/
    1234/report.csv
    abcd/report.csv
    jklm/report.csv
    5678/report.csv
```

Each CSV's has columns & content like:

```
almonds, biscuits, cookies, dog_biscuits 
123, 321, 333, 444
555, 666, 777, 888
444, 551, 555, 999 (and so on for 75 lines or so)
```

I want to put their into a combined CSV file. I'd been using exec in a PHP file to do this:

```
exec("cat /path/the_folder/*/report.csv > /path/combined.csv");
```

And then using sed to remove the duplicate "almonds, biscuits, cookies, dog_biscuits" header rows.

Now I need to take the names of the subfolders and put them into the lines of combined.csv.

So, there will be a column added to the CSV ("subfolder_name") and then in that column the name of the folder that line had come from. Something like

```
almonds, biscuits, cookies, dog_biscuits, subfolder_name
123, 321, 333, 444, 1234
555, 666, 777, 888, 1234
444, 551, 555, 999, abcd
333, 333, 111, 222, abcd
111, 222, 444, 333, abcd (etc and so on for 300 lines)
```

What is the smartest, simplest, most efficient way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
$folderList = array (
        "1234/report.csv",
        "abcd/report.csv",
        "jklm/report.csv",
        "5678/report.csv" 
);

$combinedCSV = "result_combine.csv";
$headers = array (
        "almonds",
        "biscuits",
        "cookies",
        "dog_biscuits" 
);
touch ( $combinedCSV );

$fp = fopen ( $combinedCSV, 'w' );
fputcsv ( $fp, $headers ); // Add headers
foreach ( $folderList as $file ) {
    if (($handle = fopen ( $file, "r" )) !== FALSE) {
        while ( ($data = fgetcsv ( $handle, 1000, "," )) !== FALSE ) {
            if ($data [0] == "almonds") // Remove Headers
                continue;
            fputcsv ( $fp, $data );
        }
        fclose ( $handle );
    }
}

fclose($fp);
```

I hope it helps

Thanks

Comment: Its ok you are welcome .. // Make sure you remove the multiple headers .. since they are all contained in all files

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$folder_list = array(); // USE YOUR CODE TO GET FOLDER LIST
$combined_output = "";
$folder_i = 0;
foreach ($folder_list as $folder) {
   $file = file($folder . "/report.csv");
   foreach ($file as $line_i => $line) {
      if (($folder_i == 0 && $line_i == 0) || $line_i > 0) {
         $combined_output .= $line . PHP_EOL;
      }
   }
   $folder_i++;
}

$f = fopen("combined.csv", "w+");
fwrite($f, $combined_output);
fclose($f);
```

Comment: ahh tha totally makes sense thank you! and it doesn't even have to use all that "exec". Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

TXR:

```
@header
@(output)
@header, subfolder_name
@(end)
@(next :args)
@(collect)
@folder/@subfolder/@file.csv
@  (next `@folder/@subfolder/@file.csv`)
@header
@  (collect :vars ())
@line
@    (output)
@line, @subfolder
@    (end)
@  (end)
@(end)
```

Run:

```
$ txr catname.txr folder/*/*.csv
animal, sound, subfolder_name
dog, bark, abcd
horse, neigh, abcd
cat, meow, efgh
cow, moo, efgh
```

Data:

```
$ ls -R folder/
folder/:
abcd  efgh

folder/abcd:
a.csv

folder/efgh:
e.csv

$ cat folder/abcd/a.csv 
animal, sound
dog, bark
horse, neigh

$ cat folder/efgh/e.csv 
animal, sound
cat, meow
cow, moo
```